# Can I program a check on a save on an admin page?

Tags: forms, users

Take for example the CKEditor admin page, where at file browser settings you can choose IMCE at file browser type. Then  you click Save.

Can you program this? I mean in PHP; because I could also find out which SQL query is done, and use drush sql-query, but that is not what I mean. I want to program it because I have a multisite with about 70 sites.

Thanks,

Eric J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

```
function MYMODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'MYMODULE_some_validate_function';
  $form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_some_submit_function';
}

function MYMODULE_some_validate_function($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['foo'] !== 'bar']) {
    form_set_error('foo', t('Foo must be bar'));
  }
}

function MYMODULE_some_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
  // Do something.
}
```

It's not possible to be any more specific than that as 'admin' pages vary in their structure. Most are created using a [`system_settings_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form/7), though, so there's a reasonable amount of consistency.

It's also worth noting that a form created with `system_settings_form()` saves its data in the variables table, so you can accomplish the same thing in a lot of cases with [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7):

```
variable_set('site_name', 'New name');
```

Comment: Thanks. In my_form_alter I said $form_state["values"]["filebrowser"]="imce". But I do not know how to program what you do on the UI page: click the Save  submit button. Think about all the post        data, how do I do that?